# TableView - heightForRowAtIndexPath not being called

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, heightforrowatindexpath

After going through all of the other Stack Overflow forms, I have implemented a dynamic height for one of my cells as follows:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    if(indexPath.row == 1){
        var image : UIImage = maskRoundedImage(image: UIImage(named: "Temp_Profile.png")!, radius: 150)
        cell.imageView?.image = image
        return cell
    }
    cell.textLabel?.text = TableArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(colorLiteralRed: 0.56, green: 0, blue: 0.035, alpha: 1)
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 28)

    return cell
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if  indexPath.row == 1 {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension * 3

    }
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

It seems pretty straightforward, but a debugging session is showing that heightForRowAtIndexPath is never being called. The View Controller is a UITableViewController and everything else works properly. Do any of you see any reason that this function is not being called?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: As mentioned below, UITableViewAutomaticDimension is not a value that should be used for arithmetic. returning UITableViewAutomaticDimension * 3 will have unpredictable effects.

Comment: Note that calling `heightForRowAt` can be expensive; you could also call `self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` and
    `self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 72.0 //estimated, average value` in `viewDidLoad`. Se also eg here: https://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Swift 3, the signature is:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
```

You have the old signature so it isn't recognized.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == 1 {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension * 3

    }
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Comment: For anyone who attempted to use UITableViewAutomaticDimension * 3, don't . It returns a -1 as just a signal to the tableView to make it default. Use an actual number

Comment: It's very easy to end up with the old signatures for these methods when you're copying examples from elsewhere - as we all do!.  In some cases, XCode will generate an error if Swift has moved on enough to make things invalid - but for cases like this you only get a warning.  That's you shouldn't ignore those yellow triangles.  Auto-complete should give you the correct signature, and then the rest of the function will most likely be OK.

Answer (score 16):

For me, I had to do this.

```
self.tableviewObj.delegate = self
```

So, don't forget to add delegate to self. Because heightForRowAtIndexparth is declared in delegate protocol.

Comment: yes, it worked after adding above code on viewDidLoad method. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have three controller A, B, C. A is base controller, B inherits from A, and C inherits from B. I set tableView delegate in A, and implement heightForRowAt function in B, and the problem occurred when i use C. I guess because the proxy assigned in A eventually points to C, so the method in B is not called.

Comment: If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.

Comment: In that case, (me too), and I found the solution was to define a placeholder method call in the base class and then override it in the descendants. Then it gets called.

Answer (score 0):

if you are inside a `UITableViewController`, just remember that the method has to be one that you need to `override` or the method name is wrong.

In my case I had `NSIndexPath` instead of `IndexPath` and it didn't match to the right method to be called

```
tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
```

when I corrected it to

```
tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
```

xcode would prompt for insertion of the `override` keyword.